Macroscopic movement
I heard that the concept of trajectory is lost in quantum mechanics. That made me wonder how would movement appear if we analyze something “big” like a moving ball quantum mechanically.
Do the ball's constituent atoms seemingly teleport between positions, similar to a TV displaying images with pixels turning on and off?
How can we be certain the "ball" after movement is the same collection of atoms and not a duplicate?
You compare this to the "Mexican wave" in a stadium, where the illusion of movement arises from individual people turning on and off, not actually moving across the stands.

In QM there is no ball, only a wavefunction.

In quantum mechanics, the concept of trajectory is lost due to the fact that there is a limit on the accuracy of accuracy of simultaneous measurement of position and momentum (which is given by one of the known Heisenberg relations). This is because in order to measure a particle's momentum, you have to interact with it, like bounce a photon off it, and thus affect its momentum/velocity, creating uncertainty. You can lessen the uncertainty in momentum by using smaller energy photons, which will on the other hand increase the uncertainty in position (if you want more detailed explanation, you can check out Concepts Of Modern Physics by Beiser, but that is suited for physics students). So, you either in one extreme end up with thin, seemingly one-dimensional trajectory with certain length that you don't know where to place, which is kind of pointless, or you end up with more like a sphere that you know where to place, but you don't know how big is it and you also expected a line.
Thus, the actual movement of bodies on atomic level is not known to us, so one of the answers could be we don't know (for now?) and we cannot exclude nor confirm that all bodies may be duplicates.
If you consider the question emphasizing the usage of measured data on movement of atoms, you could say that the constituent atoms teleport between positions. But particles probably don't actually teleport and some of the weirdness of quantum mechanics can be explained by wave-particle duality (that waves and particles are only an idealization of matter components, it is in fact both simultaneously) and the Heisenberg principle I've mentioned.
There is some truth in the analogy with the Mexican wave (assuming we use my latter answer). But I would modify it so people are separated into groups of few people and for each group only a single and random person can have a raised hand. We would see a similar wave, except we would notice if we moved with the wave that who raises a hand in each group seems random. But, if the groups we small and dense enough, we could not notice it and it would appear like a standard Mexican wave, in a way.
I hope that this helps. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification or more details if needed.

An object like a ball is made of a large number of particles, such as electrons, protons and so on. These particles are said to be indistinguishable, which means that the swapping two electrons (or protons or whatever) with one another won't change the probabilities of measurements on them. You can't track an individual atom, but you can say that a concentrated lump of atoms has moved this way or that way.
If you have just a single particle like an electron, it is described by a wavepacket that spreads out as it moves and can undergo interference. You can makes the wavepacket go along different possible trajectories and combine them in such a way that the probabilities of different possible outcomes depends on what happened on each path: this is called interference.
If an interfering particle undergoes an interaction that produces a record of the particle's state that can be copied, this suppresses interference: an effect called decoherence. For a small particle preventing such interactions for a period that is long compared to the time it takes to change is technologically feasible. For an object the size of a ball, which has gas molecules from the air bouncing off it, light reflecting off it and so on decoherence will take place very quickly compared to how fast the ball moves:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
As a result if you observe a moving ball you will it move along a single classical trajectory. There will be other versions of the ball moving along different trajectories but you won't see them:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
